# How to find duplicate record for same date

Tags: sql

I have a room inventory table each room has one record for each day,
but some rooms have double record for a day. I want to query to pull out those id.

Inventory_table => id, roomid, inv_date....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following may get you a list of the rooms with duplicates.

```
select id, roomid, inv_date, count(room)
from room_inventory
group by id, roomid, inv_date
having count(room) > 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Id, count(*) from inventory_table group by roomid, inv_date having count(*)>1
```

Answer (score 0):

select empno,count(*) from emp group by empno having count(*)>1;

### its with reapted values

select * from emp where rowid not iN(select min(rowid) from emp group by deptno)

Comment: Your select statement variables don't match any of those listed in the question. Are you sure you meant to answer this question? Try matching your answer to the details in the original question. Hope this helps?